# BigQuery MERGE Query: Merge tables based on condition

Tags: sql, merge, google-bigquery, dml

I was playing with the MERGE query in BigQuery and noticed that I can't update the specific rows based on the condition.
For example, I have 5 records already present in the table. I want to update only two records whose values are changed. When I execute the below query all the rows get updated. That means out of 5 for 3 records I don't want to change the values. AS soon as I'll receive new values that should change the existing records.

```
MERGE `test.organization_user` T
USING `test.user_details`  S
ON T.user_id = S.user_id
WHEN MATCHED AND 
(
  T.organization <> S.organization OR
  T.contact_number <> S.contact_number
)
THEN
  UPDATE 
  SET  
  T.organization = S.organization,
  T.contact_number = S.contact_number
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT ROW
```

Is there any solution for this kind of scenario or using merge it will update all the matching records and if we don't want to update the existing one then should we have values for all the fields for those records in the source table(from which values will get updated to the target table)?

An example is:

[image]

Comment: can you share some sample data?

Comment: @SomendraKanaujia I've updated the example in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You should handle null in condition:-**

```
MERGE `test.organization_user` T
USING `test.user_details`  S
ON T.user_id = S.user_id
WHEN MATCHED AND 
(
  IFNULL(T.organization,'') <> IFNULL(S.organization,'') OR
  IFNULL(T.contact_number,0) <> IFNULL(S.contact_number,0)
)
THEN
  UPDATE 
   SET  
  T.organization = S.organization,
  T.contact_number = S.contact_number
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT ROW
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing the answer.